# Magento Store - Add nofollow to Layered Navigation

Tags: php, magento, nofollow

Which file would I look in to add nofollow tags to my layered navigation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:

/app/design/frontend/default/YOURTEMPLATENAME/template/catalog/layer

Answer (score 1):

Yes,like magento 1.4*,pp/design/frontend/default/base/YOURTEMPLATENAME/template/catalog/layer
modify the filter.phtml,state.phtml to add nofllow tags. That is!

Answer (score 0):

open or create `app/design/frontend/<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml` and add the following XML information:

```
<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><meta>NOFOLLOW</meta></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
<catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setRobots"><meta>NOFOLLOW</meta></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered_nochildren>
```

This will set NOFOLLOW to your meta tag robots in the head of the layered navigation page.

Comment: But... do you really want the searchengine not follow every link on the page? Or only the links in template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml ? I think you want the search engines to follow the page results but not the links in the filter. add rel=nofollow to the link in filter.phtml

Comment: this is **REALLY NOT**  what OP wants.